# wordpress container cannot connect to mariadb container

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker, docker-compose

This is my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: *****
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    #network_mode: "none"
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****
    ports:
      - 8001:3306
    volumes:
      - ./configs/etc/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    restart: always
```

And this is the error I got in docker logs:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 10
```

Line 10 is the "links" one.

I also got a 502 Bad Gateway error on the front page ( I installed Nginx as a proxy in my host os to forward port 80 to 8000)

Note that the nginx proxy access logs are all returned as a 302 not 502.

Ps: I am using the [official Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/)

Comment: could you try without :mysql ? in the links section ?

Comment: I tried, same problem.

Comment: I tried another wp installation and discovered that it works with the same code but in another directory. The mysql error is in this case insignificant but I don't know from where comes the problem.

Comment: Line 10 warning does not come from docker-compose.yml. How about adding port to WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:

`WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open MariaDB port publicly, just expose port 3306 to other containers.

So in db replace:

```
ports:
  - 8001:3306
```

with:

```
expose:
  - "3306"
```

I believe that default database port in Wordpress is 3306, which is also default port in MariaDB.